# Init SqlDependency and notify changes

Tags: sql-server-2008, notifications, messaging, service-broker, sqldependency

I need something telling to my app when someone has updated data in the database. If I don't have misunderstood, SqlDependancy is what I need. I have followed [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) and write this code:

```
class dbListener
{
    public dbListener() 
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(MainWindow.dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString + "Password=12345;");

        SqlDependency.Start(MainWindow.dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString + "Password=12345;");
        connection = new SqlConnection(MainWindow.dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString + "Password=12345;");
        connection.Open();
        SomeMethod();
    }
    SqlConnection connection;
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Assume connection is an open SqlConnection.
        // Create a new SqlCommand object.

        //{
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.ArchivioErogazioni", connection))
            {
                // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                // Maintain the refence in a class member.
                // Subscribe to the SqlDependency event.
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);
                // Execute the command.
                command.ExecuteReader();
          //  }
        }
    }
    // Handler method
 void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change) 
        { 
            // Handle the event (for example, invalidate this cache entry).
            MessageBox.Show("ikjkjkj");
            Debug.WriteLine("fkldjkfjklgjf");
            SqlDependency dependency = (SqlDependency)sender;
            dependency.OnChange -= OnDependencyChange; 
            SomeMethod();
        }
    }

    void Termination()
    {
        // Release the dependency.
        SqlDependency.Stop(MainWindow.GetConnectionString("Model"));
    }

}
```

but it doesn't work. I mean, it runs without errors, but when I try to test it, updating some values from the SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, nothing happens. I have put a breakpoint in the function that would manage the event, but it is fired only in the init phase.

Have I done mistakes? How can I reach my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but it is fired only in the init phase

It fires because your query notification subscription is invalid. You **must** inspect the `SqlNotificationEventArgs` members. Only the [`Change`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0fkxc6y(v=vs.110).aspx) type is a notification for change, you are probably getting a `Subscribe` type with [`Statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlnotificationsource(v=vs.110).aspx) source. Your query does not meet the criteria described in C[reating a Query for Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181122.aspx):

> - The statement may not use the asterisk (`*`) or `table_name.*` syntax to specify columns.

Comment: I edited the query, thanks a lot for the links.

How can I check the type of the notifications correctly? I have edited the question, the OnDependancyChange method.

Comment: It seems to work, but... only for the first two changes in the selected column... why?

Comment: maybe is there something like a timer for check the frequency of the speed? and maybe am I doing the inserts too fast?

Comment: Read [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/), it explains how it works. And read [Troubleshooting Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177469.aspx) for troubleshooting advice. Also, read [SqlDependency.OnChange callback timing](http://rusanu.com/2008/01/04/sqldependencyonchange-callback-timing/) for a specific scenario you may be experiencing (debugging).

Comment: I've almost done it with this: http://jgowdy.blogspot.it/2010/01/sqldependency-query-notification-with.html 

but it fires the event also at init time... why? Did you already know this article?

Comment: (but now it seems to work, the only problem it's the firing of the event at startime)